I couldn't convert .html file to docx using pandoc as required
Trying to convert file.html to output.docx using pandoc command but failed to get desired output


pandoc .\file.html -o output.docx --reference-doc=custom-reference.docx


1st image is output , 2nd image is custom-reference , 3rd image is file.html.
[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Qs3bIS7n.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/Jp16aiq2.png)
i'm expecting convert file.html as per the style of custom-reference docx as output.docx

Please don't try to post pictures of code but post the code as text. If you have problems with reference-docs, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc
